# Jquery disable selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to apply this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/2054/) solution but without any luck :(

```
$('.select').on('keyup change', function () {
    var selected = [];
    $(".select option:selected").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") selected.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(".select:not(this) option").each(function () {
        if (selected.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        else $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

I want to make disabled all selected items from previously selected lists.

Comment: If Anyone knows how to disable selected items when new personel is added?

Comment: I solved my problem....just change the first line to this: $(document).on('click', '.select', function () {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not working because you are adding the select lists dynamically and to use the keyup and change events, you need to use delegation:

```
$(document).on('keyup change', '.select', function () {
    var selected = [];
    $(".select option:selected").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") selected.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(".select:not(this) option").each(function () {
        if (selected.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        else $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

See the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wfaaztnb/8/

Comment: Oh again this....it works now :) BUT! If a user adds new personal he can choose again already chosen ones...how to disable that?

Comment: It's not so simple after all :(

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the selector `$('.select')` with `$(document)` and that's it! :)